# PHPmyadmin Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

currently, I am using aws,ec2,and rds. I intalled phpmyadmin, and when I tried to login, I am facing the Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES). I found that I could login with my RDS master username and password, but I failed. I referred to https://www.serverkaka.com/2018/09/connect-aws-rds-mysql-instance-with-phpmyadmin.html for install phpmyadmin.

My current config.sample.inc.php is

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie. Needs to be 32 chars long.
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'MY RDS ENDPOINT';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
```

Comment: Hi, so when you try to connect to the RDS hostname with your credentials that doesn't work?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use MySQL Workbench?

Comment: just preference... but know I want to know why it is not working.

Comment: @mokugo-devops Yes!